# Change Gameobject z position inside canvas to bring it forward

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a 2D scene with an orthographic camera that has a Canvas with multiple GameObjects. These objects are actually dialogs that are displayed to the user when they click a button.

All the GameObjects are pre instantiated and I am just using `SetActive()` to display them or hide them. Now, if a user clicks on a button, they do see the GameObject as expected, but if they click on another button without closing the previous window, the new `GameObject(UI Window)` displays below the already opened window.

The only real way I have found to change that is by switching the GameObjects hierarchy order inside the Canvas. I do, however, need to change that programmatically, regardless of that.

I have tried changing z values and adding `spriterenders` with layers, but I keep seeing the same order in my Unity Editor. It only changes if I drag the GameObject and change the position inside the Canvas Hierarchy.

How can I achieve this via script ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that when your're rendering something inside Canvas the position of GameObject in hierarchy matters. Actually canvas is using order in hierarchy for z-sorting.

But you can affect the order of GameObject in hierarchy in scripts, see [Transform.SetSiblingIndex](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetSiblingIndex.html), [Transform.SetAsFirstSibling](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsFirstSibling.html) and [Transform.SetAsLastSibling](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.SetAsLastSibling.html) if you want to change the position of GameObject in hierarchy

Comment: But What if I'm using Horizontal Layout? For example, I'm making a card game. cards in hand need to show the one I'm hovering on, to the most top. But I don't want to change the order of the card.